# Repeated Measures analysis of variance

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics

I am new user of R software. I have 2 types of experiments.

1. I want to analyze data from 10 jujube varieties and harvested fruits at 4 maturity stages.
   The effect of varieties is fixed while that of harvesting stages is random.
2. I harvested fruits of two varieties and applied 4 different treatments to these fruits and analyzed on weekly basis up to 35 days.
   I want to use repeated measures ANOVA. Kindly help me some workable commands and helpful R packages. An response will be highly appreciated. Thanking in advance

dataset for first case

```r
head(data, 10)
   sub  varieties stages width
1    1     Anokhi     S1 27.08
2    1     Anokhi     S1 27.15
3    1     Anokhi     S1 26.87
4    1 Desikarela     S1 26.21
5    1 Desikarela     S1 23.47
6    1 Desikarela     S1 23.77
7    1   Dilbahar     S1 30.38
8    1   Dilbahar     S1 26.80
9    1   Dilbahar     S1 29.69
10   1       Gurh     S1 20.57 

(str(data, 10) 'data.frame':    120 obs. of  4 variables:  $ sub      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  $ varieties: chr  "Anokhi" "Anokhi" "Anokhi" "Desikarela" ...  $ stages   : chr  "S1" "S1" "S1" "S1" ...  $ width    : num  27.1 27.1 26.9 26.2 23.5 ...)

dataset for second case

(head(data, 10)    sub   var   trt stor   TSS 1    1 Umran NoHWT 0day 10.00 2    1 Umran NoHWT 0day  9.70 3    1 Umran NoHWT 0day  9.80 4    1 Umran  HWT1 0day 10.20 5    1 Umran  HWT1 0day  9.75 6    1 Umran  HWT1 0day  9.86 7    1 Umran  HWT2 0day  9.65 8    1 Umran  HWT2 0day  9.72 9    1 Umran  HWT2 0day  9.81 10   1 Umran  HWT3 0day  9.45)

(str(data, 10) 'data.frame':    144 obs. of  5 variables:  $ sub : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  $ var : chr  "Umran" "Umran" "Umran" "Umran" ...  $ trt : chr  "NoHWT" "NoHWT" "NoHWT" "HWT1" ...  $ stor: chr  "0day" "0day" "0day" "0day" ...  $ TSS : num  10 9.7 9.8 10.2 9.75 9.86 9.65 9.72 9.81 9.45 ...)
```

I am using following commands in R software for Repeated measures ANOVA. Whether these are workable or suggest me best alternates.

```r
library(car)
 options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly")) 
          
 model <- lm(vitc ~ varieties+stages+varieties:stages, data=data) 
               
 Anova(model, type="III")        
                                                 
 library(agricolae)              
                                        
 (HSD.test(model, "varieties")$groups)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 (HSD.test(model, "stages")$groups)
```

Comment: What is your research question ? Also, please desribe the dataset. Please list *all* the variables and explain what they are, and what kind of values they may take.

Comment: 1. To study the effect of jujube varieties and level of harvest maturity on physical, chemical and phytochemical attributes of fruit. The datasets are comprised of 120 obsevations 10 varieties * 4 stages * 3 replicates for each quality parameter.

Comment: 2. in second situation, jujube fruits from 2 varieties were harvested and treated with 3 hot water dippings at different time temperature combinations and 4th one serve as control. fruits after treatments were stored at 5C and analyzed on day 0 as well after one week interval for different quality parameters up to 35 days. The objective is to investigate the effect of varieties, treatments and storage interval on quality attributes of jujube fruits.

Comment: Kindly suggest me workable commands and useful R packages to solve these as repeated measures ANOVA and Tukey's HSD test for multiple mean comparison.

Comment: Parameters are fruit length, frimness, TSS, Acidity, Vit C Etc. These are physical, chemical and phytochemical parameters and may take continuous values.

Comment: I can send One example from each but donot know how to add file as an attachment in comments.

Comment: Thank you for this info. What kind of example do you want to send ? The actual data ? You could upload it to an external site and post the link here. Or, you could just post part of the data by editing your original post. For example, you could post the output from `head(mydata,10)` and `str(mydata)` which will show the first 10 rows and the details of the variables. When posting code (or output), please enclose with 3 backticks (```)  at the start and tend of the block and then the system will then format it nicely.

Comment: Please don't use comments for that. Please edit the original post and add it there

Comment: OK. I have deleted comments and add supporting data in previous post